# "As far as I know" v.s. "as I know"

Tags: usage

> As Katy Perry has sung,“After hurricane comes a rainbow.” We should bravely face the hardship together.

In this sentence,"as" means "in the same way".
Thus,can the following sentence make sense by the similar usage?

> As I know,hasty decision is always looked back on with regrets. You should do it before thinking twice.
>
> I want to mean"According to my experience,hasty decision is always looked back on with regrets. Thus,you should do it before thinking twice."

The reason why I ask this question is that I often see sentences like"As far as I know, trauma is all she left for him."

I've never seen someone use"as I know" without "as far". Moreover,my teacher said using "as I know" alone was wrong. However,she didn't know why it was wrong. That is to say,she wanted the sentence like

> As far as I know,hasty decision is always looked back on with regrets. You should do it before thinking twice.

So,can I just use "as I know" like the sentence above? If it is wrong,why?

Is there any difference between"as far as I know" and" as I know"?

Comment: Short version of the question: `As far as I know` vs `As I know`

Comment: @AlexanderMadyuskin TBH,it is a good idea. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"As far as I know" means "to my knowledge".** This phrase implies that perhaps the speaker does not have all of the facts or information, so the notion that follows the phrase may be incorrect.

> As far as I know, the car worked yesterday. (Perhaps it does not work anymore?)

**"As I know" is not commonly used, but it is not exactly wrong.** It might be used when explaining your own thought process, for example. It parallels the common phrase "as you know", which shows that the speaker does not think that they are sharing unknown information with the listener.

**"As I know well" asserts that the following statement is correct** and is quite emphatic.

It is probably a good idea to use "as far as I know" when you are *not* trying to make a strong assertion and "as I know well" when you *are* trying to make a strong assertion, and simply avoid "as I know".

Comment: Wow……What an extremely comprehensive answer you gave！The reason why I should avoid"as I know" is that it is used as if I talk to myself but it doesn't give  listeners more information like whether I am sure it is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help so much. That does help me to understand English more .：)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing grammatically wrong there, but I think idiomatically I would add a "well":

> As I know well, ....

or even the slightly more literary

> As I well know, ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me what meaning of "well" is in your sentence? I got no idea.xd Moreover,if I just use "as I know" , would you accept it or think it is odd?